# Definitions of fractional Sobolev Spaces

Tags: sobolev-spaces, functional-calculus, fractional-sobolev-spaces

In a paper I read that for a bounded domain $W^{s,p}(\Omega)=\{ u \in L^p(\Omega), (id-\Delta)^{s/2}u \in L^p(\Omega) \}$ and $s$ is not assumed to be an integer, $p \neq 2$ in general.

If $p=2$ the borelian calculus in Hilbert spaces allow to define $id-\Delta)^{s/2}$ so that I understant the definition of $W^{s,2}$.

> How one can define the operator $(id-\Delta)^{s/2}$ when $p \neq 2$ ?
>   Is there a borelian calculus in reflexive Banach spaces?

Comment: There are several ways to introduce fractional Sobolev spaces. The most "abstract" one is based on the fact that $-\Delta+I$ is a positive-definite self-adjoint operator on $L^2$, so that it possesses a fractional power.

Comment: Yes but the problem is that on $L^p$, $p \neq 2$ self-ajointness is meaningless since $L^p$ is not a Hilbert space. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The common approach is via harmonic analysis, Bessel kernels, and so on. Roughly speaking, this operator is firstly defined as a distribution, then hard estimates show that it can be defined on $L^p$ functions. It is a standard theory, but far from being trivial. You can find more on the book by Adams, *Function spaces and potential theory*, Springer-Verlag.

Comment: It depends what do you mean by "define" the operator $(id - \Delta)^\frac{s}{2}$. If you just want to see that it is defined in a dense domain you can take test functions. I guess the difficult part is either to prove that it is closable or that its formal inverse $(id - \Delta)^{-\frac{s}{2}}$ is a globally defined bounded operator on $L^p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respect to your question. No, i do not think there is an analogue of the continuous functional calculus in non-Hilbert spaces. Nevertheless you can still use holomorphic functional calculus. I think the most straightforward way of showing that $(id - \Delta)^{-\frac{s}{2}}$ is globally defined for $L^p(\Omega)$ is to use the following ''trick'':

1. The heat semigroup $e^{t \Delta}$ is a globally defined contraction in every $L^p(\Omega)$
2. You can express $(id - \Delta)^{-\frac{s}{2}}$ as a formal integral of the elements $e^{t \Delta}$, i.e.:
   $$
     (id - \Delta)^{-\frac{s}{2}}
     = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s/2)} \int_0^\infty t^{s/2} e^{-t} e^{t \Delta}\, \frac{d \, t}{t}.
   $$

You can check that the formula above holds in $L^2(\Omega)$ using functional calculus. It extends to $L^2 \cap L^p$ and, since $L^2 \cap L^p$ is dense in $L^p$, and the formula above define a bounded function in $L^2 \cap L^p$, it extends to he whole $L^p$.